# Display a new member to an html display list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a new member to an html display. I'm working with a json object array. I have two functions, one that displays a list in membersList and another that is supposed to push a single member to the list. I'm not clear on what I'm doing wrong, maybe the way I'm passing (or not) the function? I'm getting [object][object] in my list ... see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/njndcyqm/

```
// Display the members list inside the id 'membersList' on the html page
function displayMembers() {
    //console.log("dislpaying members");
    var len = members.length;
    var membersList = document.getElementById('membersList');
    membersList.innerHTML += '';

    // loop through each member object in the array, and print each element (member string) to the pge
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //console.log(members[i]);
        // get the members
        membersList.innerHTML += members[i] + '<br>';
    }
    //console.log(members);
}

/* This functions displays a single member on the page.
 *
 * @param member - a single member from the members array
 */
function displayMember(member) {
    // get the html membersList
    // var membersList = document.getElementById('membersList');
    // console.log("display members list:" + membersList);
    // Declare a string to hold member 
    var myMember = member.memberFirstName.value + ' ' + member.memberLastName.value + ' ' + member.memberEmail.value;
    // What's in myMember?
    console.log("What's in myMember:" + myMember);
    members.push(myMember);
    //console.log("This is membersList" + members);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to insert an object into html. That would be like trying to do this in C#: `txtFirstName.Text = personObject;` It just doesn't work that way. You have to do something like this:

```
membersList.innerHTML += '<div>' + members[i].memberFirstName + '<div>' + '<br>';
```

Comment: Ah yes, this works:
 membersList.innerHTML += members[i].memberFirstName + members[i].memberLastName + members[i].memberEmail + '<br>';

Comment: Or better yet, this:
        membersList.innerHTML += '<span>' + members[i].memberFirstName + ' ' + members[i].memberLastName + ' ' + members[i].memberEmail + '</span> <br>';